# Which one should I choose? "was" vs "is"

Tags: past-tense

Which one is correct?

> Did you think he **was** right?
>
> Did you think he **is** right?

Comment: Both could be correct, depending upon context, but the first sentence agrees in tense. It requires a _very_ complicated context to make the second sentence appropriate; it would have to be established that the correctness of _he_ is a timeless fact.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - True, but if we change the first word from _did_ to _do_, the sentence is fine: "Do you think he's right?"

Comment: @J.R. Of course; that causes agreement in time (or tense.) To me, this is interesting and evocative of [**this**](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/17528/192771) (among many...)

Comment: @DavidC I don't understand what you describe in _expressing his views at that time._ Do you refer to reported speech, as in _Did you think: "he is right?"_ See the link in my comment above for many & many an iteration of this discussion.

Comment: @P.E.Dant If someone expresses a view, one of his hearers can ask another hearer "Do you think he is right." In fact, until some time has passed, that is the way they must express it.

Comment: @DavidC  The OP's sentence is not in the present tense. It is _**Did** you think he is right?_

Comment: @P.E.Dant Opps, missed that somehow.

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan You ask interesting questions, but they often lack _detail,_ and this can cause them to be closed, by vote or unilaterally by a moderator. If you add more detail—your reasons for asking the question, or a short explanation of your research and what confuses you—your question has a better chance of being left open. Please read [**Details, please.**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example sentences, you need to keep the verb tenses consistent ties the actions

> *Did* you think he *was* right?

both in the past

> *Do* you think he *is* right?

both in the present

> *Do* you think he *was* right?
>   *what do you think now about something he did in the past*

to ask about a present thinking of a past action

> *Did* you think he *is* right?

is incorrect since you could not have though about a current action in the past.